# Plotting 2D function and other 3D functions coincidently

Tags: plotting

`ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == z, 2 y == z, x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 1}, 
      {x, -2, 2}, {y, -0.5, 1}, {z, 0, 2}]`

The above isn't what I'm seeking. I'd like to plot $x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 = 1$   in 2D, so as a circle on the xy-plane ($z = 0$), 
in the same graph as the other two functions that I'd like  in 3D. How would I do this?

halirutan's answer nearly resolves this, but his plot still contains $x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 = 1$ in 3D for all $z$.
 I want solely the trace in the xy-plane, for the combined plot of all 3 functions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get rid of the 3D surface $x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 = 1$ in halirutan's plot? Just remove it from the `ContourPlot3D`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TKsvo.png (although I prefer http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJ3R.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is not completely clear. What you can do is the following: You make a 2d contour plot of your second equation and transform this into a 3d graphics by appending a 0 (z=0) to all `Line` points appearing in the 2d graphics and turning the lines into `Tube`'s:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == z, 2 y == z, 
   x^2 + (y \[Minus] 1/2)^2 == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -0.5, 1}, {z, 0, 
   2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.3]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, 
   Cases[Normal[
     ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1/2, 1}]], 
    Line[pts_] :> Tube[Append[#, 0] & /@ pts], Infinity]}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. Thanks. I emended my question. Do you seize it now?

Comment: @LePressentiment So you don't want a *combined plot*? Your 2d graphics can be obtained by `ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2},{y, -1/2, 1}]]`. The question remains, what do you want to do with this 2d graphic?

Comment: Thanks. I do want a combined plot. I've emended my question again. Does this answer your question: "The question remains, what do you want to do with this 2d graphic?"